# Rotation matrix in Eigen

Tags: eigen

Can I use the Eigen library to get the rotation matrix which rotates vector A to vector B?
I have been searching for a while, but cannot find related api.

Comment: "The" rotation matrix which rotates vector A to vector B is ambiguous: there are multiple rotation matrices which send A to B. The method provided in the answer gives one such matrix.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You first have to construct a [quaternion](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1QuaternionBase.html#ac35460294d855096e9b687cadf821452) and then convert it to a matrix, for instance:

```
#include <Eigen/Geometry>
using namespace Eigen;

int main() {
  Vector3f A, B;
  Matrix3f R;
  R = Quaternionf().setFromTwoVectors(A,B);
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that this requires an additional `.toRotationMatrix()` after `(A,B)` to work, as `R` is a Matrix.

Comment: No, there is an overload of operator= that makes it work. However, the respective is explicit, therefore `Matrix3f R = Quaternionf().setFromTwoVectors(A,B);` requires `.toRotationMatrix()` or to explicit cast to a `Matrix3f(.)`, or to explicitly call the ctor with `Matrix3f R(Quaternionf().setFromTwoVectors(A,B));`

Comment: Sorry my mistake! Missed that slight subtlety. Thanks for explaining the differences.

Comment: Is there an option for 2D vectors? If my understanding of Quaternions is correct (which I doubt, because I've never worked with them), they're specifically for 3D stuff.