# OpenGL/Glut draw Pyramid - Skeleton Bones

Tags: opengl, 3d, glut, freeglut

I would like to draw a human skeleton (pose estimation project) in OpenGL, using whichever toolkit might be helpful.
I already have something simple working, drawing the joints with

```
glvertex3d // and/or 
glutWireSphere
```

and the bones with

```
glBbegin(GL_Lines)
glvertex3d // coordinates of starting point
glvertex3d // coordinates of ending point
glEnd()
```

This looks like very similar to the next picture, however this bone depiction doesn't give any intuition about bone rotation.

[image]

I would like to have something looking more similar to the following picture, with bones drawn as elongated pyramids.

[image]

Glut doesn't seem to help on this.

```
glutWireCone // better than simple line, but still no intuition about rotation
glutWireTetrahedron // not really useful / parametrizable
```

Is there any tool available or should this be a custom solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GLUT objects will be drawn using the current OpenGL modelview matrix.  This can be used to control the position, rotation, or even the scaling of the rendered object.  With a cone, you would first translate (using `glTranslate()`) to the position of one end point, and then rotate (using `glRotate()` or `glMultMatrix()`) so that your cone was pointed towards the other endpoint.  Finally you call your `glutWireCone()` method so that the height is equal to the distance from one endpoint to the other.

The tricky bit is finding the `glRotate()` parameters.  GLUT will draw the cone by default along the Z axis, so your rotation needs to be whatever rotation would be required to rotate the Z axis to the axis defined by your end point minus your start point.  The GLM math library can be really useful for this kind of thing.  It even has a [function](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.5/api/a00222.html) for it

```
quat rotation(vec3 const & orig, vec3 const & dest)
```

So you could do something like this:

```
// these are filled in with your start and end points
glm::vec3 start, end; 
glm::vec3 direction = end - start;
glm::quat rotation = rotation(glm::vec3(0, 0, 1), direction);
glm::mat4 rotationMatrix = glm::mat4_cast(rotation);
glMultMatrixf(&rotationMatrix);
```

You can get the tetrahedron effect by specifying 3 for the number of slices in your glut cone.  In fact I wouldn't be very surprised if `glutWireTetrahedron` wasn't implemented in terms of `glutWireCone`

Comment: Thanks Jherico, great answer!!! I just had this working following your advice. Thanks also for pointing me to GLM, I never used it before and seems to be extremely helpful, I hope I was pointed to this much earlier :) Your answer is of course accepted, but I will also post my code snippet for future reference by other (noting down the #includes and some comments)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment above, Jherico's answer really helped me solve this problem.

This answer builts uppon his post, just to make things a bit more complete, for future reference.

Please find the GLM library [here](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.5/index.html), it's a header only library, so you don't need to build this, just link to it and include the necessary header files. It has some great tools, as can be seen below.

```
#define GLM_FORCE_RADIANS // for compatibility between GLM and OpenGL API legacy functions
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>    // for glm::mat4_cast // casting quaternion->mat4
#include <glm/gtx/quaternion.hpp>  // for glm::rotation
#include <glm/gtx/string_cast.hpp> // for glm::to_string
...
...
...
// _startBoneVec3 used below is Eigen::Vector3d
// _endddBoneVec3 used below is Eigen::Vector3d
...
...
...
//
// for JOINTS
//
glPushMatrix();
    glTranslated( _startBoneVec3(0),_startBoneVec3(1),_startBoneVec3(2) );
    glutWireSphere(1.0,30,30);
glPopMatrix();
...
...
//
// for BONES
//
glPushMatrix();
    float boneLength = ( _endddBoneVec3  - _startBoneVec3 ).norm();
    glTranslated(        _startBoneVec3(0),_startBoneVec3(1),_startBoneVec3(2) );
    glm::vec3 _glmStart( _startBoneVec3(0),_startBoneVec3(1),_startBoneVec3(2) );
    glm::vec3 _glmEnddd( _endddBoneVec3(0),_endddBoneVec3(1),_endddBoneVec3(2) );
    glm::vec3 _glmDirrr   = glm::normalize( _glmEnddd - _glmStart ); // super important to normalize!!!
    glm::quat _glmRotQuat = glm::rotation( glm::vec3(0,0,1),_glmDirrr); // calculates rotation quaternion between 2 normalized vectors
  //glm::mat4 _glmRotMat = glm::mat4_cast(_glmRotQuat); // quaternion -> mat4
    glm::mat4 _glmRotMat = glm::toMat4   (_glmRotQuat); // quaternion -> mat4
  //std::cout <<  glm::to_string(_glmDirrr) << std::endl;
    glMultMatrixf(glm::value_ptr(_glmRotMat));
    glutWireCone(4.2,boneLength,4,20); // cone with 4 slices = pyramid-like
glPopMatrix();
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: no reason to use `glTranslated` instead of `glTranslatef`.  I'm not sure what norm() does.  That might be more clear if it was glm::length(_endddBoneVec3  - _startBoneVec3);

Comment: True, I am just used to working with doubles most of the time. The function `norm()` is a function of the library Eigen, which I heavily use, and it does the same thing with your proposal. The code-snipet was pasted from my code, but for this example the function `glm::length` might indeed be more intuitive.

Comment: Just an additional note, a similar solution is also provided by Eigen, noted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043130/rotation-matrix-in-eigen).